# Subnetting confusion

Tags: networking, subnet

Okay, studying Networking at university and I cannot remember the answer to a very simple question.

Can different subnet's have the same subnet mask?

IE Subnet 1 Range: 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.31 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.224
Subnet 2 Range: 192.168.0.48 - 192.168.0.79 also with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.224

Are these two both valid subnets, or do the masks have to be different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The subnet mask is a measure of how large a subnet is; of course different subnets can have the same subnet mask: what's important is that they actually are *different*, and don't overlap.

It's like asking if two countries can have the same size: yes, of course... but if they try to occupy the same land, war will ensue.

Comment: I thought this was the case and thanks for clearing it up! I just keep running into a problem with cisco routers when setting up subnets with overlapping IP's and just wanted to check this wasnt the issue. Must be miscalculating my subnet sizes